# How to get hex integer from a string in JS?

Tags: javascript, hex

I would like to convert this: `"#FFFFFF"` to this: `0xFFFFFF`. How is it possible without using eval?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I am *sure* this is a duplicate... I wish the "related questions" were smarter about language tags :-/

Comment: @ Danny: By "hex value," do you mean the **numeric** value FFFFFF hex (e.g., 16777215 decimal?). If so, just say "numeric value," putting the word "hex" in takes us into string land. I think you probably meant numeric, though.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder I edited the title

Comment: I have just answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48140695/best-way-to-convert-hex-string-with-hash-to-hex-value-with-0x-in-javascript/70607982#70607982

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Strip off the "#" and use `parseInt()`.

```
var hex = parseInt(str.replace(/^#/, ''), 16);
```

Then, if you want to *see* it in hex, you can use `.toString()`:

```
console.log(hex.toString(16));
```

Comment: I would prefer `substring()` (as in @TJCrowder's answer) over `replace()`, for efficiency's sake.

Comment: @MarkReed: It totally depends on what the OP *really* wants, which isn't clear from the question. It may be (given the lack of quotes on `0xFFFFFF`) that the OP wants then numeric value (which, of course, would make the title of the question completely wrong -- not the first time!).

Comment: @TJCrowder: Your reply seems to be on the wrong answer. :)  All I said above was that I would use `substring(1)` instead of `replace(regex)` for this problem.

Comment: @Displee yes it does?

Comment: @Pointy parseInt("#797e61".replace(/^#/, ''), 16); gives me 7962209 as result, and not 0x797e61.

Comment: @Displee of course, because the normal way to display numbers is in base 10, not base 16.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```js
var resultP = document.getElementById('result');
var btn = document.querySelector('button');
var input = document.querySelector('input');
function convert(hex) {
  return Number(`0x${hex.substr(1)}`);
}
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  resultP.innerHTML = convert(input.value);
})
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hex code to hex integer</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" maxlength="7" />
    <button>Done</button>
    <br />
    Result:
    <p id="result"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's desirable that you give a brief explanation how the code solves the problem in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this code:

```
function hex2num(hexcode){ return Number(  '0x' + hexcode.split(/[^0-9a-fA-F]+/).join('')  ) }
```

This function will strip out all characters that are not numbers between 0-9 or alphabetical characters between A-F before trying to parse the input. The output is a number, because `0x009 === 9` in JS.

This solution works when dealing with numbers that are less than the MAX SAFE INTEGER (9007199254740991) but if the hex code equates to a number larger than that you will probably need to use a different solution.

> > Expected Usage:
>
> - `hex2num('#0000FF') === 255      // true`
> - `hex2num('#FFFFFF') === 16777215 // true`
> - `hex2num('0x000000000001') === 1 // true`
> - `hex2num('0L0L4') === 4          // true`